# useSubscription working in React but if failing to listen to subscriptions in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have the following graphql client which i'm implementing with [graphql-sse](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/sse/recipes#with-apollo):

```
import {
  ApolloLink,
  Observable,
  split,
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  FetchResult,
  Operation,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { getMainDefinition } from "@apollo/client/utilities";
import { createUploadLink } from "apollo-upload-client";
import { KEYS, serverDomain } from "../constants";

import { print } from "graphql";
import { createClient, ClientOptions, Client } from "graphql-sse";
import { retrieve } from "../utils";

class SSELink extends ApolloLink {
  private client: Client;

  constructor(options: ClientOptions) {
    super();
    this.client = createClient(options);
  }

  public request(operation: Operation): Observable<FetchResult> {
    return new Observable((sink) => {
      return this.client.subscribe<FetchResult>(
        { ...operation, query: print(operation.query) },
        {
          next: sink.next.bind(sink),
          complete: sink.complete.bind(sink),
          error: sink.error.bind(sink),
        }
      );
    });
  }
}

const requestLink = new ApolloLink(
  (operation, forward) =>
    new Observable((observer) => {
      let handle: any;
      Promise.resolve(operation)
        .then(async (operation) => {
          const jwt = await retrieve(KEYS.TOKEN_KEY);
          if (jwt) {
            operation.setContext({
              headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
              },
            });
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          handle = forward(operation).subscribe({
            next: observer.next.bind(observer),
            error: observer.error.bind(observer),
            complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
          });
        })
        .catch(observer.error.bind(observer));
      return () => {
        if (handle) handle.unsubscribe();
      };
    })
);

const wsLink = new SSELink({
  url: `https://${serverDomain}/graphql`,
  retryAttempts: 10,
  headers: () => {
    return {};
    // const jwt = await retrieve(KEYS.TOKEN_KEY);
    // if (!jwt) return {};
    // return {
    //   Authorization: `Bearer  ${jwt}`,
    // };
  },
});

const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: `https://${serverDomain}/graphql`,
  credentials: "include",
});

const splitLink = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query);
    return (
      definition.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
      definition.operation === "subscription"
    );
  },
  wsLink,
  ApolloLink.from([requestLink, httpLink])
);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: splitLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  credentials: "include",
});
```

When i try to make a subscription from a react client as follows:

```
import { gql, useSubscription } from "@apollo/client";

const Doc = gql`
  subscription OnNewFriendRequest($input: OnNewFriendRequestInputType!) {
    onNewFriendRequest(input: $input) {
      message
      friend {
        id
        nickname
      }
    }
  }
`;
function App() {
  const { data, loading } = useSubscription(Doc, {
    variables: {
      input: { id: "ef7c5256-80f0-4de0-9893-51f3e3e9926e" },
    },
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ data, loading }, null, 2));
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <pre>
        <code>{JSON.stringify({ data, loading }, null, 2)}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Everything works i get the following data for this subscription request:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "onNewFriendRequest": null
  },
  "loading": false
}
```

When i try it in react native as follows:

```
 const { data, loading } = useSubscription(Doc, {
    variables: {
      input: { id: "ef7c5256-80f0-4de0-9893-51f3e3e9926e" },
    },
    onData({ data }) {
      console.log({ data });
    },
  });

 console.log(JSON.stringify({ data, loading }, null, 2));
```

The only log that i get is the loading state of first subscription which looks as follows:

```
{
  "loading": true
}
```

Clearly this shows me that this subscription is not listening to other comming subscriptions. Can someone tells me why am i getting this behaviour.